# Regular expression too loose

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following Regex

```
Regex(@"(^http|https)://(w){0,3}(\.)?(.)*lycos\.(.)*/(.)*(&|\?)(q|query)=(.)*")
```

I want that to match against:

```
http://search.lycos.com/web?q=cautare
```

but it should not match against:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.3.9&utms=1&utmn=932580756&utmhn=search.lycos.com&utmcs=utf-8&utmsr=1920x1080&utmvp=1920x979&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=11.6 r602&utmdt=searchmeup - lycos&utmhid=2063854819&utmr=0&utmp=/web?q=searchmeup&utmac=ua-2342215-18&utmcc=__utma=1.950014844.1362381742.1362387055.1362404209.3;+__utmz=1.1362387055.2.2.utmcsr=lycos.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/;&utmu=qlag~
```

IS there a way to make the regex more restrictive ?

Comment: Do you have specific things you want it to match/not-match? Do you want it to explicitly match `http://[domain]/[path]?q=[value]`, or is there any dynamic-ness to the pattern you want to match?

Comment: The Regex pattern is used just to make sure that the url is a url search made with lycos. After this I extract other infos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(.)*` (which should really be `.*`) matches *anything* (except linebreaks), that's why your pattern is so permissive.

So instead of

```
Regex(@"(^http|https)://w{0,3}(\.)?.*lycos\..*/.*(&|\?)(q|query)=.*")
```

you could apply other tokens than `.`, for example `[^/]` for non-slash characters, `\w` for alphanumeric characters or `\S` for non-space characters:

```
Regex(@"(^http|https)://w{0,3}(\.)?\w*\.lycos\.[^/]*/[^&?]*(&|\?)(q|query)=\w*")
```

Comment: Sounds better indeed. I just have to amke sure I understand all the limitations of the new one :-)

Comment: Don't understand the .[^/]*/[^&?]* part

Comment: @Gmt: If you can clearly define the restrictions on what the regex may match, then it's easy to write a precise regex.

Comment: `[^/]*`: Match any number of characters except slashes; `[^&?]*` match  any number of characters except ampersands or question marks.

Answer (score -1):

You could greatly simplify your regex.

1. You are very liberal in your capture groups `()`. You only need them when you have something you want to *capture* or you have more than one regex character you want some modifier to effect. So you can change all the `(.)*` into `.*`.
2. The `w{0,3}(\.)?` part is completely pointless with the `(.)*` part, so kill it.
3. I'm not quite sure what you are doing with the `^`, it looks to me that it will only match "http" when it starts at the beginning of a line. It'll match "https" anywhere. So either remove it, or place it outside the parens.
4. `(http|https)` is equivalent to `https?`
5. `.*` matches anything that's not a line break character. Lets be more restrictive. Domain names can only contain letters, numbers, periods, and hyphens -> `[0-9a-z\-]`
6. Tim's answer suggests to use `[^&?]*`. That'll work as long as you know you aren't going to get a mess of URLs in one string. It could match "http://www.lycos.com/movies blah blah blah blah http://www.google.com/?query=blah" for example. You'd want to add more restrictions to protect from that.
7. After the last "." in the domain name, you'll want to match at least 1 character for the URL to be considered possibly valid. So use a `+` instead of a `*`

   ```
   Regex(@"https?://[0-9a-z\-.]*lycos\.[0-9a-z\-.]+/[^&?]*(&|\?)(q|query)=\w*");
   ```